# blank page displayed after logging into ecp with exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013

I have just installed Exchange 2013 into a test environment for a testing lab.

Install of prereqs (update AD schema and prep AD) and software was successful.

I go to https://serveraddress/ecp and I get the login page - I enter correct credentials but then get taken to a blank page - no errors.

Issue occurs on IE/Chrome/Firefox.

Issue occurs using the browser on exchange server or a remote PC.

Issue occurs if I use IP or FQDN in place of serveraddress in url above and same if I use 127.0.0.1 when on the exchange server itself.

I have it running on 2012 R2 standard.

From my google searches I have tried:

1. Updating Exchange - no on CU11 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971270)
2. Tried disabling SSL in IIS (https://superuser.com/questions/737399/microsft-exchange-2013-on-server-2012-owa-shows-blank-page)
3. Ensuring the IIS bindings are correct and changed IP from localhost IP to actual server IP (https://www.fatframe.com/2014/08/25/blank-owa-ecp-pages-logging-on-exchange-2013/)
4. Created a new self-signed certificate and tried using that in the IIS bindings.
5. Recreating the OWA virtual directories (http://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2013-eac-ecp-blank-screen/)

Still my issue remains.

Can anyone advise how to resolve from here?

Let me know if I can post any logs to provide more information.

Comment: It happens to me sometimes. I just refresh or reenter the http://servername/ecp/ URL and it works.

Comment: Refreshing or re-typing the servername/ecp has no effect - still shows a blank page - I have never got past the blank page so have never been able to get in and setup mail flows etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue after setting ecp and owa directory to Windows authentication in power shell [here](http://www.networksteve.com/exchange/topic.php/Exchange_Server_2013_ECP_Login/?TopicId=40197&Posts=0)

```
set-ecpvirtualdirectory -Identity "ecp (default web site)" -windowsauthentication $true -formsauthentication $false
```

Perform an `ipconfig /flushdns` on your desktop.

log in to your ecp with `https://yourservername/ecp/?exchclientver=15`

Comment: I tried this now when I log in instead of getting a bank page I get the following error: Server Error in '/ecp' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\web.config' because access is denied.

[No relevant source lines]